# Jenkins Jobs directory - taking a lot of space

Tags: jenkins

Thanks for looking into my concern.

I see some of my jenkins jobs are occupying a lot of space in the server. If I check in the /user/.jenkins/jobs/job-name/builds directory, I have many builds in the history. Do I really need to keep them ?

Comment: Only you can know that answer, I have some jobs which keep very little history, for a major project you might need to be able to reproduce and then build so I tag on git, create a BOM etc. It depends on what you need it to keep.

Answer (score 1):

You likely do not need all of them, depends on your needs and how you deal with it but if you go to the job's configurations you can see the option to remove old builds and keep a certain limit. For example here it's set to discard old builds after 500 builds. You can do by days or build count. Up to you really, I would tune it to how much space your builds usually take vs how much space your server has.

[image]

If were to just throw out numbers (since don't know how large your builds are nor the size of your server). I would say if you're limited on space maybe 5 last builds or 1 week of builds. I would use number of builds if you build frequently per day or if you do a few builds a day maybe time is fine.

Here's the Jenkins Help as well for reference:

> This determines when, if ever, build records for this project should
>   be discarded. Build records include the console output, archived
>   artifacts, and any other metadata related to a particular build.
>   Keeping fewer builds means less disk space will be used in the Build
>   Record Root Directory, which is specified on the Configure System
>   screen.
>
> Jenkins offers two options for determining when builds should be
>   discarded:
>
> 1. Build age: discard builds if they reach a certain age; for example,
>      seven days old.
> 2. Build count: discard the oldest build if a certain
>      number of builds already exist.
>
> These two options can be active at the
>   same time, so you can keep builds for 14 days, but only up to a limit
>   of 50 builds, for example. If either limit is exceeded, then any
>   builds beyond that limit will be discarded. You can also ensure that
>   important builds are kept forever, regardless of the setting here —
>   click the Keep this build forever button on the build page.  The last
>   stable and last successful build are also excluded from these rules.
>
> In the Advanced section, the same options can be specified, but
>   specifically for build artifacts. If enabled, build artifacts will be
>   discarded for any builds which exceed the defined limits. The builds
>   themselves will still be kept; only the associated artifacts, if any,
>   will be deleted.
>
> For example, if a project builds some software and
>   produces a large installer, which is archived, you may wish to always
>   keep the console log and information about which source control commit
>   was built, while for disk space reasons, you may want to keep only the
>   last three installers that were built.  This can make sense for
>   projects where you can easily recreate the same artifacts later by
>   building the same source control commit again.
>
> Note that Jenkins does not discard items immediately when this
>   configuration is updated, or as soon as any of the configured values
>   are exceeded; these rules are evaluated each time that a build of this
>   project completes.

Comment: Thanks Richard.
I know that I can use build discarding in job config.

My actual concern is how important this data is ? At what scenario, I may need this data again ?

Comment: That's really a case by case basis and depends on what the build jobs do? Maybe more information about your job would help. If it's running tests such as Unit Tests then maybe last 5 builds or 1 weeks worth is a good start. If it's a job that runs benchmarking then maybe longer to have more data for trending. Etc.